# Jquery animate opacity and margin on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an link that when clicked, has to show 2 other links.
But when I click my link, nothing happends. Really nothing.

I have loaded in jquery before I have my script.

**This is my jquery script:**

```
   $("#imd").toggle(function(){
    $("#anw").animate({opacity:1},200);
    $("#3d").animate({marginTop:75}, 200);
},function(){
    $("#anw").animate({opacity:0},200);
    $("#3d").animate({marginTop:0}, 200);
});
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
#anw {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #0f0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**And this is my HTML markup**

```
<div class="mid">
    <h1><a href="#anw" id="imd">Interactive Media Design</a></h1>

    <div id="anw"><br><a class="left" href="website.html">Apps</a><a class="right" href="website.html">Websites</a></div>

    <hr> 

    <h1 id="3d"><a href="#">3D Modelling</h1>

</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <h1><a href="3dsmax.html">Contact and about me</a></h1>
</div>
```

My apologies if this is a very dumb question, but I have no clue.. Also the documentation I can find is not filling my needs.

Comment: What link do want to hide when clicked and what links do want to show when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with a `click` handler:

```
$("#imd").click(function(){
    $("#anw").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},200);
    }, function() {
         $(this).animate({opacity:0},200);   
    });
    $("#3d").toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginTop:75}, 200);
    },function() {
        $(this).animate({marginTop:0}, 200);
    })
});
```

See the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lpvty1w/

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle for what you want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/rr9Lvjgh/
Essentially:

```
 $("#imd").on('click', function(){ 
  // code to change stuff here
 });
```